# Finding the default style for a type in code behind

Tags: wpf, code-behind, wpf-style

In WPF, you can create a `Style` that acts as the default for a control type in XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}">
    . . .
</Style>
```

Then, when WPF goes to display that control, it looks up that `Style` from the resources based on the its type.

I want to do the equivalent of this in the code-behind of my program.  How do I find that `Style`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can search for the style in the Application-level resources by using the control type as the key:

```
Style defaultStyle = Application.Current.TryFindResource(typeof(MyControl)) as Style;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
object globalStyleDefinedByApp;
Style globalStyle = new Style(typeof(TargetType));
if (Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue(typeof(TargetType), out globalStyleDefinedByApp))
{
    globalStyle = globalStyleDefinedByApp as Style ?? globalStyle;
}
```

In case somebody lands here looking for a solution for Universal Windows Projects (UWP), no `TryFindResource` exists so the above is how you have to do it.