# Howto Change Generic Xaml Style Property in Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

When you write a `xaml` anonymus style( without key) in `App.xaml` resources, it applies to all `TargetTypes` in application.

i.e:

```
<Style TargetType="SplitView">
    <Setter Property="OpenPaneLength" Value="110"/>
</Style>
```

Makes all `SplitView`'s `OpenPaneLength` to 110.
 
Are there any ways to change a property of anonymous style in runtime programatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123714/finding-the-default-style-for-a-type-in-code-behind